# Flutter - FutureBuilder - Search

Tags: flutter

I am using a FuturBuilder for a List of Users. I get the users through the futur: fetchpost() via API. At the start at column I implemented a Searchbar. So how can I implement that my Searchbar is searching?

```
Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchPost(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Container(
                child: ...CircularPro..(),
                ),

            } else {
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {

                        },
                        controller: searchController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(  
                            title: Text(
                              "[" + 
                              snapshot.data[index].id + "] " + 
                              snapshot.data[index].firstname + " " +
                              snapshot.data[index].lastname
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to take some variable for condition on `ListView` and set that variable's values on search bar's submit event then `setState()` of widget.

```
String searchString = "";
```

---

```
TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState((){
                             searchString = value; 
                          });

                        },
                        controller: searchController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        ),

                      ),
```

---

```
 ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return snapshot.data[index].firstname.contains(searchString)? ListTile(  
                            title: Text(
                              "[" + 
                              snapshot.data[index].id + "] " + 
                              snapshot.data[index].firstname + " " +
                              snapshot.data[index].lastname
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
...

:Container(),
```

Comment: But is it possible the search in more terms f.e firstname, lastname, and is?

Comment: Yes . Use && operation in condition .

Comment: Like that: `snapshot.data[index].firstname.contains(searchString) && snapshot.data[index].lastname.contains(searchString)`?

Comment: Yes just like that.

Comment: That doesn't work. He search both at the same time and not separate from each other

Comment: Use || for Or condition and && for And condition. Now try it with || .

Comment: Happy coding ;)

Comment: Unnecessary empty list display while searching @VrushiPatel

Comment: @VrushiPatel this is not the best solution using setState will cause it to re-render and the api calls will be made again

Comment: API call should not be made again. Put it into init() method that will not triggered by setState(). @swamper